# How to force content-compression on specific mime type with app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing a Javascript application which needs to load a lot of files. I want to transfer an uncompressed tar file and let app-engine and the browser to do the compression transparently. I encountered that if the mime type is "application/x-tar" app-engine will never use content compression! If I force app-engine to use "application/xml" as mime-type everything works as expected and content-compression is used. I have tried other mime types like "application/octet-stream" which will not be compresses too.

How can I force app-engine to compress a file with mime-type like "application/x-tar"?